# Cant implement conditional types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a wrapper function, which would return promise. Result of this promise is depending on wrapper parameters - if I send no callback then result is string, if I send callback then the result is a callback ReturnType .

My current implementation:

```ts
type UnknownFnT = (...args: any) => any

type PromiseRes<T> = Promise<
    T extends UnknownFnT ? ReturnType<T> : string
>;

export const timePromise = async <FnT extends UnknownFnT>(
    ms: number,
    callback?: FnT,
    ...args: FnT extends UnknownFnT ? Parameters<FnT> : void
): PromiseRes<FnT> => {
    if (callback) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                const res = await callback.apply(args);
                resolve(res);
            }, ms);
        });
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            resolve('ok');
        }, ms);
    });
};
```

My idea is that if callback is not undefined then I return its returnType, other way - string type. But I get then this error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(FnT extends 
UnknownFnT ? ReturnType<FnT> : string) | PromiseLike<FnT extends UnknownFnT ? 
ReturnType<FnT> : string>'
```

Maybe I'm wrong with generics? How to make this work? Please help me out...

Comment: You can't implement generic conditional types this way without type assertions, see [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Generally if you want to abstract over functions like this you should make it generic in the args type and return type directly.  (so `(...a: A)=>R` instead of `FnT`) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WPK5em). (more...)

Comment: (...continued) Even so, you'll need a type assertion to tell the compiler that when `callback` is omitted, that you can be sure `R` is `string` (since it's technically untrue, see [ms/TS#49158](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49158)). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write this up as an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?